# Excel opens file created by EPPlus with error

Tags: excel, epplus

I created excel file by EPPlus with 2 sheets: data and chart on the data.
Excel can open the file without any errors.

Now, I read (by EPPlus) and save the file again without any changes and Excel opens the file with error message and doesn't show chart.

[image]
[image]
`xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error118920_01.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file 'file.xlsx'</summary><removedParts summary="Following is a list of removed parts:"><removedPart>Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part.  (Drawing shape)</removedPart></removedParts></recoveryLog>`

Comment: Those errors are very generic so will not tell us much unfortunately.  Best thing to do would be to paste your code that created it and then reopened/saved it.

Comment: Create sample https://github.com/constructor-igor/TechSugar/tree/master/EPPlusSamples but I cannot reproduce the issue with help of the sample. Right now, I cannot publish production code,

Comment: Tough to diagnose if it is not reproducible.  Maybe post the problem file?

Comment: added test (including source and problematic target excel files) ProductionFile_OpenSave_CannotBeOpened in https://github.com/constructor-igor/TechSugar/tree/master/EPPlusSamples/EPPlusTests

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for such a late answer.  Seems like that Excel file has a bad reference in the chart x-axis.  If you go to Select Data of the chart and hit Edit on the right for the Category axis labels you will see this:

[image]

But that `='Charts'!` looks like a broken reference.  Seems that Epplus cannot handle that very well - should probably log it as a bug.  So, to fix it cancel out of that, click on the charts x-axis and hit delete.  Should look like this after:

[image]

Save the file and run it though your unit test and it opens properly for me.

Ernie

Comment: I defined series by next code                 string yName = String.Format("'" + dataWorkSheet.Name + "'" + "!{0}2:{0}{1}", columnName, rowsCount);
                var excelChartSerie = chart.Series.Add(yName, "");